# Game entities: Handling collisions

Tags: entity-relationship, collision

I'm trying to make a 2D game (my first one). I'm not looking for algorithms to determine whether or not objects collide, but rather how I should organize everything. I'm having great difficulty in figuring out what responsibility should go to which so class, so much so that I started feeling stupid. =))

I guess my principal classes are `Entity` (and its children) and `EntityManager`. What interface should Entity provide, for example? How should entities become aware that they are in collision with another entity — should the manager perhaps update them and pass a `CollisionEvent` to the `handleCollision` function of each entity? Any suggestions are more than welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that EntityManager contains all entities so the manager is the one who needs to check collisons between all entities. like this

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < totalEntities ; ++i)
 for(int j = i+1 ; j < totalEntities ; ++j)
 {  
  CollisionInfo info;
  if( CheckCollision(entities[i], entities[j], info) )
  {
     // Okay, what we should do? I suggest two solutions

     // 1. simple one
     entities[i].OnCollide(info);
     entities[j].OnCollide(info);

     // 2. event-or-message driven system
     EventManager::Instance()->SendEvent(COLLISION_EVENT, info)
  }
}
```

The first one is probably the simplest one. However, what if there are some other objects which are interested in this collision event? like sound, logging or scoring system? Even entities are which not related to that collision might want to "know" this event so that they can change their behavior. (Think a boss monster gets more angry when its kids are killed by you!)

So, to make it more flexible, #2 has come. First, you need to have your own `event-or-message system` ( you can think it as Windows message system ) where objects can subscribe specific messages they want to handle. Then, EntityManager can simply propagate collision events by sending messages. Entities can subscribe this collision message type and they should know if they need to handle this particular collision by examining the info. Likewise, your scoring system can subscribe it and calculate new score for kills.

If the game is simple enough, you could go for #1 but I highly recommend #2 and you will be very satisfied with it. Good Luck! :)